# List sum of numbers that are multiple of other numbers

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have the following problem:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

This is my code I have used to attempt to solve the problem (Edit1 being the output, and Edit2 being the number that the problem is raised to):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var i, answer : longint;
begin
  answer := 0;
  for i := 0 to strtoint(Edit2.text) - 1 do begin
    if i mod 3 = 0 then answer := answer + i;
    if i mod 5 = 0 then answer := answer + i;
  end;

  Edit1.Text := inttostr(answer);
end;
```

Inputing the number 10 into Edit2 (editbox) will output: 23, as the problem states. Inputing the number 13 into Edit2 will output 35, which is also correct

For some reason, when raising the input to 1000, the output is given as: 266333; which, when entered as an answer, is regarded incorrect.

EDIT: I have altered the code to account for double counting, here is the updated version:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var i, answer : longint;
begin
  answer := 0;
  for i := 0 to strtoint(Edit2.text) - 1 do begin
    if i mod 3 = 0 then answer := answer + i;
    if i mod 5 = 0 then begin
      if not i mod 3 = 0 then begin
        answer := answer + i;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  Edit1.Text := inttostr(answer);
end;
```

This is still not giving the correct answer.

Comment: Try with 15, see if you can figure it out.

Comment: Double counting... That explains it

Comment: You want to add to `answer` if _either_ the number is a multiple of 3 _or_ a multiple of 5 (or both) so try: `if (i mod 3 = 0) or (i mod 5 = 0) then answer := answer + 1;`.

Comment: `not` is evaluated first, like  `(not i) mod 3`. Use the logic as explained by @TripeHound. (Although it should read `answer := answer + i`).

Comment: Simpler logical expression: if (i mod 3 = 0) or (if i mod 5 = 0) then... And use for i := **1** to ...

Answer (score 3):

You are double counting. Any number that is a multiple of both 3 and 5 will be counted twice. What's more you may as well start the loop from 1 rather than zero. You can fix the code like this:

```
answer := 0;
for i := 1 to strtoint(Edit2.text) - 1 do begin
  if (i mod 3 = 0) or (i mod 5 = 0) then
    answer := answer + i;
end;
```

However, the code is easier to understand if you separate it from your user interface. And you may as well make it more general. So, your code might read like so:

```
function SumOfMultiples(const N: Integer; 
  const Candidates: array of Integer): Integer;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 1 to N-1 do
    for j := 0 to high(Candidates) do
      if i mod Candidates[j] = 0 then
      begin
        inc(Result, i);
        break;
      end;
end;
```

The key here is the use of `break`. Once we have found that a number is a multiple, we increment the running total, and break out of the inner loop. This avoids the double counting.

To find the sum of multiples of 3 and 5, that are less than 10 you would write:

```
SumOfMultiples(10, [3, 5])
```

I'm sure that it would be possible to optimise the code to avoid any looping. You would need to do the following:

1. Sum the multiples for each candidate. This can be done directly with a handful of divides and multiplies but without any looping.
2. Account for the double counting. This can be done by looking at the multiples of products of candidates.

The implementation is simple enough, at least for pairs of candidates:

```
function SumOfMultiples(const N, k: Integer): Integer; overload;
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  Assert(N>0);
  Assert(k>0);
  Count := (N-1) div k;
  Result := k*Count*(Count+1) div 2;
end;

function SumOfMultiples(const N, k1, k2: Integer): Integer; overload;
begin
  Assert(k1<>k2);
  Result := SumOfMultiples(N, k1) + SumOfMultiples(N, k2)
    - SumOfMultiples(N, k1*k2);
end;
```

I guess it would be a little more tricky for more than two candidates. Anyway, that's not the question here, but it might make a nice fun project for a rainy day!